# Matrix Multiplication in hadoop

Tags: java, algorithm, hadoop, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I try to build a code for page rank algorithm, and in that the main complexity is to solve matrix multiplication efficiently, but I didn't understand how this task be perform, I read some papers on that, but that is beyond of my range. I didn't understand the concept that he apply.
So, can you give me a concept behind mapper and reducer function for matrix multiplication. Thanks in advance.

I read this [link](http://www.norstad.org/matrix-multiply/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you can break matrix multiplication into subproblems with something like the [Strassen Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) and then send those subproblems to a bunch of different computers.  Once those subproblems are finished the summing together of the different subproblems into the matrix itsself can also be handled with.  The key to using Mapreduce is that all of the subproblems can basically be computed in parallel, which is... what Mapreduce is for.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of frameworks like [Apache Hama](http://hama.apache.org/) have [implementation](http://wiki.apache.org/hama/PageRank) of the PageRank. [Apache Giraph](http://incubator.apache.org/giraph/) also has support for [Pagerank](http://giraph.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/giraph/examples/SimplePageRankVertex.html%5C).

MapReduce is not well suited for PageRank, so Google published [Pregel paper](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2009/06/large-scale-graph-computing-at-google.html) for large scale graph computing.

Answer (score -2):

The link you provided explains this as clear as anything (plus it includes source-code). If you're still struggling with the concepts of the operations, then you should probably start by reading up some more on matrix/linear algebra, so you understand the underlying mathematics.

Comment: It does not answer the question, might be better as a comment.

Comment: @amit The questioner is saying "teach me matrix multiplication with map/reduce", my response is to suggest reading up on linear algebra and understanding the mathematics. How is that not an answer? Or are you expecting someone to post a full lecture-series with references and exercises?

Comment: can you give me the basic concept behind mapper and reducer function.

Comment: @jhamb - again, what more precisely is it that you are struggling with? The concept of map and reduce functions in the context of MapReduce or the specific implementations in the article you posted for matrix multiplication? Be more precise, make an effort to try the implementation and if you run into more specific problems then people might be able to guide you further. As it is now, you're not asking a question about a problem, you're wanting someone to teach you a whole concept. Can you see how that's maybe a bit too big for a Q&A forum?

Comment: No I know the basics of Hadoop and Map-Reduce algorithms, my question to you is that in the avove link that I mentioned in question is that what is the meaning of first paragraph of strategy one?